# bundle.js not accept any change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, bundle

this is my component i try to add any new things is not appear

```
import React from 'react'

export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div>

     <div className="main">
          <img className="today_img" src={this.props.imagedayA}/>
          <p className="tempdayA">{this.props.tempdayA}<span className="degree">&deg;</span></p>
          <img className="night_img" src={this.props.imagenightA}/>
          <p className="tempnightA">{this.props.tempnightA}<span className="degree">&deg;</span></p>

          <img className="line" src="simplyamman_assets/images/divider.png"/>
          <img className="linedown" src="simplyamman_assets/images/divider.png"/>

          <img className="tomday_img" src={this.props.imagedayB}/>
          <p className="tempdayB">{this.props.tempdayB}<span className="degree">&deg;</span></p>
          <img className="tomnight_img" src={this.props.imagenightB}/>
          <p className="tempnightB">{this.props.tempnightB}<span className="degree">&deg;</span></p>
     </div> 
   </div>
  }
})
```

i try to add hello word in div but its not added i think the problem from bundle .js it take one change in component how i can solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running `npm run bundle`? Changes to the source are not compiled unless you bundle them up with browserify.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to see changes immediately while you're developing, you can run webpack development server:

`webpack-dev-server --config <config file location> --hot --inline` and it will hot-swap any recompiled code